# Can I play videos in YouTube Standalone player in Android using YouTube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

And what if the content is copyrighted?
Can I still display those videos in app in youtube's official standalone player?

Answer (score 0):

Of course your Android app can display copyrighted videos but you might get in trouble as per the [Youtube Fair Use Guidelines](https://www.youtube.com/yt/copyright/fair-use.html#yt-copyright-myths):

> The four factors of fair use In the United States, fair use is
>   determined by a judge, who analyzes how each of the four factors of
>   fair use applies to a specific case.
>
> **1. The purpose and character of the use, including whether such use is of commercial nature or is for nonprofit educational purposes**
>
> Courts typically focus on whether the use is “transformative.” That
>   is, whether it adds new expression or meaning to the original, or
>   whether it merely copies from the original. Commercial uses are less
>   likely to be considered fair, though it’s possible to monetize a video
>   and still take advantage of the fair use defense.
>
> **2. The nature of the copyrighted work**
>
> Using material from primarily factual works is more likely to be fair
>   than using purely fictional works.
>
> **3. The amount and substantiality of the portion used in relation to the copyrighted work as a whole**
>
> Borrowing small bits of material from an original work is more likely
>   to be considered fair use than borrowing large portions. However, even
>   a small taking may weigh against fair use in some situations if it
>   constitutes the “heart” of the work.
>
> **4. The effect of the use upon the potential market for, or value of, the copyrighted work**
>
> Uses that harm the copyright owner’s ability to profit from his or her
>   original work are less likely to be fair uses. Courts have sometimes
>   made an exception under this factor in cases involving parodies.

You can read more on that link for additional info.